# Topic 1.6 by Kernighan and Ritchie

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, char, digits

I was going through the book "The C Programming language" by Kernighan and Ritchie and I am stuck at a topic.

Topic number 1.6 talks about Arrays. In the book, they have included a program that counts the digits, white spaces and other characters. The program goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main(){
       int c,i,nother,nwhite;
        int ndigit[10];

        nwhite=nother=0;
        for(i=0;i<10;++i)
            ndigit[i]=0;

        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
            if (c>='0' && c<='9')
                ++ndigit[c-'0'];

            else if (c==' '|| c=='\t'||c=='\n')
                ++nwhite;
            else
                ++nother;


            printf("digits:");
            for(i=0; i<10;++i)
                printf(" %d",ndigit[i]);
             printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",  nwhite, nother);


}
```

First, I don't understand the purpose of the first for loop that is :

```
 for(i=0;i<10;++i)
             ndigit[i]=0;
```

And secondly, I can't understand the logic behind this part of the while loop:

```
if (c>='0' && c<='9')
                ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

I really need someone to explain me the logic behind the program so that I can move further with C programming.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is counting the occurence of each character digit `'0'..'9'`. The `c-'0'` reduces the character `'0'..'9'` to a value `0..9` which then indexes the array, with `++ndigit[c-'0'];` incrementing the count of each numeral.

Comment: It's almost 30 years since I had read it, but I guess if you read (and understand the text) between the program samples, you should also understand the program samples ;-) Picking a random program sample from the book, and trying to understand it, most likely won't work for beginners...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop

```
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
             ndigit[i]=0;
```

is used to set all elements of array `ndigit` to 0. The array will count numbers of eneterd digits.

Instead of this loop you could initially initialize all elements of the array to 0 when it was declared.

```
int ndigit[10] = { 0 };
```

As for this statement

```
if (c>='0' && c<='9')
                ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

then if the entered char is a digit `c>='0' && c<='9'` then expression `c-'0'` gives you the integer value of the digit. Characters that correspond to character constant `'0' - '9'` internally in the computer memory represented by their ASCII or some other coding scheme codes. For example cgaracter `'0'` in ASCII has internal code `48`, character `'1'` - `49`, character `'2'` - `50`  and so on. For example in EBCDIC cgaracter `'0'` has another code `240`, character `'1'` - `241` and so on.

The C Standard guarantees that all digits follow each other.

So if variable `c` keeps some digit then expression `c - '0'`  gives number from 0 (if c keeps '0' ) to 9 (if c keeps character '9' ).

This value (from 0 to 9) is used as an index in array `ndigit`.

For example let assume that c keeps character `'6'` . Then `c - '0'` will equal to integer number 6. So ndigit[6] is increased

```
++ndigit[c-'0']
```

This element of the array with index 6 counts how many times character '6' was entered.

Comment: This explanation is full of external knowledge. Thanks for your help.

Comment: int ndigit[10] = { 0 ); should probably be int ndigit[10] = { 0 };

Comment: @LeoR Thanks. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

`ndigit[i]` holds the number of times digit `i` (0-9) was counted. E.g., `ndigit[5]` contains the number of times the digit `5` was counted. So the first loop just initializes all to `0`, as nothing was seen thus far.

The if statement checks whether the current character `c` is a digit. If so, it determines which digit it is by subtracting `'0'` from it. This will give the desired index, for which the value contained is increased by one.

Comment: That was a great explanation for me.Thanks for the help.:)